# PrestaShop - show price with tax included, and not excluded

Tags: prestashop

I'm currently working on a webshop, and this is a problem that has been bugging me for a while now.

On all my products (in the product tab etc.) the prices are shown without taxes. In Denmark we do have a rule stating that taxes need to be shown. The only way for my costumers to see the taxes is in their shoppingcart summary. This is not ideal for me.

I really hope for you guys help!

Best Regards,
Christian O'dwyer
christianodwyer@outlook.com

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon your question during lookups.

First of all the basics
http://www.templatemonster.com/help/prestashop-1-6-x-show-prices-includingexcluding-the-tax.html

Then there's the tax setting in Prestashop which might override settings:
Products - Prices (tab) - Tax rule (select)